# Changing a global structure in a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I defined a structure as follows:

```
typedef struct myStruct{
    char *val1;
    char *val2;
    struct myStruct *prev;
    struct myStruct *next;
} myStruct;
```

I also wrote a function to add a node to this structure:

```
void add_to_struct(struct myStruct *strct, char *val1,
                    char *val2){

    // create the node for new element
    struct myStruct *my_new = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
    my_new->val1 = val1;
    my_new->val2 = val2;
    my_new->next = strct;
    my_new->prev = NULL;   

    strct->prev = my_new;
}
```

Adding a node to the struct using this function doesn't seem to work though. I guess the problem is that I do not pass my structure (which I defined as a global variable) by reference correctly, but I don't know why. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
How I call it:

```
void main(){
    struct myStruct *headPrev = Malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *));
    struct myStruct *headNext = Malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *));
    char *headval1 = Malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLEN);
    char *headval2 = Malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLEN);

my_struct = Malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct)); 
    my_struct->prev = headPrev;
    my_struct->next = headNext;
    my_struct->val1 = headval1;
    my_struct->val2 = headval2;

    newVal1 = "abcd";
    newVal2 = "bl";
    ....
    add_to_struct(my_struct,newVal1,newVal2);    
}
```

Comment: C has no notation of references - this may be the first clue - you need to fix the title

Comment: If you think you are passing it incorrectly, it would help to see your global variable declaration and how you call the function.

Comment: `struct myStruct *headPrev = Malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *));` and `struct myStruct *headNext = Malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *));` allocate memory told hold a pointer. I'd assume that you want to initialize `*headPrev` and `*headNext` with `NULL` instead. Also instead of using `sizeof(char) * MAXLEN` you can just use `MAXLEN` as `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks pretty close, just a few minor issues --

my_new should be allocated to be sizeof(struct myStruct)), not cacheElement, no?

also, this looks like a linked list, but you need to return my_new so you can use it as the new head of list.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use void add_to_struct(struct myStruct **strct, char *val1, char *val2).

```
void add_to_struct(struct myStruct **strct, char *val1,char *val2)
{
    // create the node for new element
    struct myStruct *my_new = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
    my_new->val1 = "abcd";
    my_new->val2 = "efgh";
    my_new->next = strct;
    my_new->prev = NULL;   
    (*strct)->prev = my_new;
}
```

Comment: it should then be `(*strct)->prev = my_new`

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating memory using malloc and collecting the address of the memory using `my_new` variable. So the function is doing nothing effectively. Let me provide an anology. A man comes to ask water at your home. You should either take `his` bottle, fill it with water and give it back. Or you can give your own bottle to him filled with water. But you're simply taking your own bottle, filling it with water and keeping it to yourself.

You either have to do `return my_new` or use `strct=malloc....` and also change argument of sizeof to `myStruct`